# importing emoji codes into jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, jupyter, emoji

Jupyter notebooks support markdown cells however it doesn't seem to support emoji codes. I suppose one way might be using html to import icons like [fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

Anyone have a workaround?

**Edit:** asked directly on the jupyter Github [#2199](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2199#issuecomment-280533674)

Comment: You can already use emojis in markdown - just copy and paste them in☺️.

Comment: Visit http://getemoji.com, copy any of the emoji of your choice and paste in **MARKDOWN** cell of **Jupyter Notebook**. It will work.

Comment: Looks like does not supports: `:warn:` etc.

Answer (score 6):

Install emoji package:

```
pip install emoji --upgrade
```

then :

```py
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Hi there! :revolving_hearts:'))
```

output:

**Hi there!**

Comment: Note that this only works in `code` cells, not `Markdown`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use colored [emojis](https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/emoji/emoji_v3.0/unicode_emoji_v3.0_characters_all.cfm) in `Markdown` just copy the hexadecimal representation into the `Markdown` cell.

For instance, for  (grinning face) use `&#x1F600;`